# force screen output before a Thread.sleep

Tags: java, android

If I try to do a screen output (Toast or setContentView) before a Thread.sleep it will not be displayed until after the sleep (or all the sleeps in the thread).  This means that if I do an output after the Thread.sleep it will overwrite the first output.  If I so a forceLayout on the View before calling the Thread.sleep it does no good.  It appears that Android stores up all the output and displays them at the end of the program.  If I run such code as straightforward Java apps on the PC it works as just fine as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do a `sleep()` on the UI thread, because that will block your entire UI (as you noticed).

If you want something to happen after a certain amount of time, you can post a delayed message by creating a `Handler` and using its [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess one must always use postDelayed() instead of sleep().  The problem is that if I want a series of changing delay times the calls to postDelayed() must be nested (which is a bit of a chore) instead of a simple sequence like with sleep().

Comment: Or you could just call postDelayed() multiple times with increasing timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

Hand the job to a Handler. I hope you aren't doing Thread.sleep on the UI thread, because that will always cause the screen to freeze (and possibly your program to be terminated as unresponsive).